# How do I use FlashVars with ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, parameters, documentation, flashvars

I found this guide for using the flash parameters, thought it might be useful to post here, since Flash CS3 lacks a usage example for reading these parameters.

See answers for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why [his example](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html) calls LoaderInfo. The [DisplayObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) class has its own (readonly) [loaderinfo](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#loaderInfo) property.  As long as your main class extends a DisplayObject, you can call the property directly

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        public function Main() {
            var test1:String    = '';

            if (this.loaderInfo.parameters.test1 !== undefined) {
                test1 = this.loaderInfo.parameters.test1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the doc:

> Returns a LoaderInfo object containing
>   information about loading the file to
>   which this display object belongs. The
>   loaderInfo property is defined only
>   for the root display object of a SWF
>   file or for a loaded Bitmap (not for a
>   Bitmap that is drawn with
>   ActionScript). To find the loaderInfo
>   object associated with the SWF file
>   that contains a display object named
>   myDisplayObject, use
>   myDisplayObject.root.loaderInfo.

Answer (score 1):

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

The entire article is at:

http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html

Important note! This will only work in the main class. If you'll try to load the parameters in a subclass you'll get nothing.